# Complex keys for bucket aggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to return a more complex key for a bucket aggregate in Elasticsearch? The default is to use a string:

Query:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "file.name" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "file.name"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "level" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "level"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "file.name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "test-1.pdf",
                "doc_count": 3,
                "level": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                        "key": "Warning",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    }, {
                        "key": "Error",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Here I have my aggregates bucketed by file name. I really need more fields than just the name. For instance, I'd like to see the ID for the document:

```
{
    "key": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "test-1.pdf"
    },
    "doc_count": 3,
    "level": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [{
            "key": "Warning",
            "doc_count": 2
        }, {
            "key": "Error",
            "doc_count": 1
        }]
    }
}
```

I haven't found anything that fits this requirement. The closest I've found is a script metric which will allow me to tokenize the fields into a string:

Query:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "file" : {
      "terms" : {
        "script" : {
          "inline" : "doc['file.id'].value ? doc['file.id'].value + '|' + doc['file.name'].value  : null"
        },
        "size" : 1000
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "level" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "level"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "file": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "f-2|test-1.pdf",
                "doc_count": 3,
                "level": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                        "key": "Warning",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    }, {
                        "key": "Error",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose this will work but it feels a little dirty. Am I missing a better option? I figure there must be some other creative solutions to this problem.

Comment: why not simply using a `top_hits` sub-aggregation with `"_source": "file.id"` ?

Comment: interesting... if I do that and limit the size to 1, that might work out well.

Comment: will this approach have a negative effect on performance? seems like maybe a subquery per result may be issued? I'm not sure what's going on under the covers here

Comment: I don't think so. Best is to try it out on your data set and measure ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I still need to build up a good test set to put some pressure on it. I'll update with an answer if it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a potential solution based on Val's comments. It uses the top hits sub-aggregation to include the extra fields I need into the response.

It's a pretty verbose response. I still need to load test this to see what performance is like. I'll come back and mark as answered if it performs well and there aren't any better solutions.

Query:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "file_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "file.id"
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "level": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "level"
                    }
                },
                "top_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "fields": ["file.name", "file.path"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "file_id": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "f-2",
                "doc_count": 3,
                "level": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                        "key": "Warning",
                        "doc_count": 2
                    }, {
                        "key": "Error",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }]
                },
                "top_hits": {
                    "hits": {
                        "total": 3,
                        "max_score": 1.0,
                        "hits": [{
                            "_index": "logs-current",
                            "_type": "workspaceLog",
                            "_id": "log-5",
                            "_score": 1.0,
                            "fields": {
                                "file.name": ["test-1.pdf"]
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparison on 300k records with aggregation limit of 500: noSciptOrTopHits=421ms,scriptedKey=698ms,topHits=1346. I think we're just going to use the scripted solution to tokenize the string but I'll leave this as a potential for others in case it's useful.